# How pass model and View Date to PartialView?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How pass model and View Date to PartialView?

my code is but show Error:

```
 <%Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Location/location.ascx", new MVCLocation.Models.LocationModel(), (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["unit"]); %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly pass `ViewData` items to the partial views as parameter. Yo can access the `ViewData` item in partial view.